# Github Super linter - How to customize the rules for C# linter?

Tags: c#, github-actions, lint, super-linter

I am trying to integrate GitHub super linter as an Action. Their documentation provided environment variables for other languages if we want to provide a custom rule file. For C#, that provision is not there. How can I add custom rules for super linter in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# Super Linter relies on the `dotnet format` command. You can configure `dotnet format` [using an `.editorconfig` file in your repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/configuration-files#editorconfig).

For example:

```
# C# files
[*.cs]

#### Core EditorConfig Options ####

# Indentation and spacing
indent_size = 4
indent_style = space
tab_width = 4

#### .NET Coding Conventions ####

# this. and Me. preferences
dotnet_style_qualification_for_method = true
```